# How to force font reload in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

There is an html page with custom font. By some reasons server sometimes doesn't provide the font. In that case I need to reload font using *the same url*.

I expected that removing all styles from the page followed by adding them back will help.
But such way doesn't work in Google Chrome. How can it be fixed?
I'm interested in a way without page reload.

Code example for testing (nodejs is used as server): https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JeBp/hcaRZgGSC

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Font test</title>

<script>document.cookie = 'send-the-font=0'</script>

<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(ArefRuqaa-Regular.ttf);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa';
  font-style: normal;
  color: blue;
}
</style>

<p>Just some text</p>

<button id="retry">Retry</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('retry').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.cookie = 'send-the-font=1';

  var style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

  for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
    style[q].remove();
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
      document.head.appendChild(style[q]);
    }
  }, 1000);
}); 
</script>
```

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var file = decodeURIComponent(request.url.substr(1));
  var headers = {};

  console.log(file);

  switch(file) {
    case "":
    case "index.html":
      file = "index.html";
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
      break;

    case "favicon.ico":
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/x-icon';
      break;

    case "ArefRuqaa-Regular.ttf":
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'font/opentype';

      if (request.headers.cookie && request.headers.cookie.indexOf('send-the-font=1') !== -1) {
        console.log('  allowed');
        break;
      }

      /* Falls through */

    default:
      console.log('  404');
      response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('Not found!');
      return;
  }

  fs.stat(file, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('An error occured while loading file information :(');
    } else if (!data.isFile()) {
      response.writeHead(403, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('Not a file');
    } else {
      headers['Content-length'] = data.size;
      response.writeHead(200, headers);
      fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response);
    }
  });
}).listen(8081);
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607498/178988)

Comment: Have you tried using `<link>` element to load `css` at `document`?

Comment: @guest271314, webpack uses `style`, not `link`, so I didn't check what happens with the `link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Chrome uses some caching for styles and if a style with same content is added again (doesn't matter if it's the same style tag, or the other) it doesn't request the font.

It can be fixed by updating style content:

```
document.getElementById('retry').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.cookie = 'send-the-font=1';

  var style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

  for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
    style[q].innerHTML += " ";
  }
});
```